# Accessing a printer from Ubuntu client to Windows server

Tags: 12.04, windows, printing

I installed a Windows server 2008 R2 and an Ubuntu 12.04 and could connect the Ubuntu to the server using likewise. The FTP is also set up. I did depoly the printer in server and another client, a Windows 7 PC can access it. (upon double click I see the print queue). However, I can't get my Ubuntu to see it, no matter how much I Google-d for the answer. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try accessing `localhost:631` and adding a network printer on Ubuntu?

Comment: I tried a great many things. This one, where exactly to access it? I mean, settings/printer, but where inside of that?

Comment: On your Ubuntu system, read `man cups;man cups-browsed`. Run a browser on your Ubuntu system, and access `http://localhost:631`

Comment: after dowloading `cups` and typing what you said in the browser, I got a form with a lot of options. that's cups, right? if so, where to next?

Comment: [waltinator](http://askubuntu.com/users/25618/waltinator) I set up cups on the Ubuntu and I'm using [biopdf](http://www.biopdf.com/) for the pdf printer. it works on my other client, the windows 7 as the printer was shared and depolyed from the windows server, but I can't connect to it from the Ubuntu. It says "connecting to printer" for a long time then it couldn't access the printer. Any ideas?

Comment: @http://askubuntu.com/users/622710/agiro:  It smells like an authentication problem. Look for hints in `/var/log/cups/*`.